# How can I make an UIImageView change depending on the chosen number?

Tags: ios, swift, output

I'm creating an app which chooses two random cards out of a 52-card deck. Then, if one of the card is strong (in my case, strong cards are "10" or stronger) I want it to show an image "yes" (tick). If both of the cards are weak, then I want it to show an image "no" (cross). I've been trying to find a problem, but every time I change something, a new type of error occurs.

I tried to set an unknown output type in func resultOfShuffle, I tried creating and naming an outlet for my UIImageView couple of times.

```
let cardArray = ["1.png", (...), "52.png"] 
 // All of the cards, from 2 to Ace (with every color). Number "33" is a card 10.
```

...

```
let cardResults = ["yes.png"]
```

...

```
@IBOutlet weak var theResult: UIImageView!
```

...

```
func randomizeCards() {

    chooseCardOne = Int.random(in: 0 ... 51)
    chooseCardTwo = Int.random(in: 0 ... 51)
```

...

```
func resultOfShuffle(firstCard : Int, secondCard : Int) -> UIImageView {

    if firstCard > 33 {

    return theResult.image = UIImage(named: cardResults)
}
}
```

**And now, the return of the last func resultOfShuffle is wrong - telling me: *Use of unresolved identifier 'theResult'*.** I also tried to find the solution to this problem, but it is kinda tricky and I don't get it.

That's how my app looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f5Rh.jpg

Comment: The error says you didn't declare `theResult` property so clearly! What is your exact problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is every statement executed in the same `ViewController`?
It should recognize `theResult` as a `UIImageView`, then.

### Update

The problem is, as solved in the comments, based on the scope of the function declaration. Since it is declared *outside* of the class where `theResult` is defined, it can't get access to it.

The solutions could be passing the variable as an argument to the function, or declaring the function in the same scope of the variable - inside the `ViewController`.

### Other notes

You are, anyway, trying to return something with this line:

```
theResult.image = UIImage(named: cardResults)
```

which doesn't evaluate to a type, but simply sets the image of the view to what's in `cardResults`. Therefore, you shouldn't return anything, but merely using this function in order to update the content of the view - this means you should use a `Void` return type.

Furthermore, you are passing to the image initializer a `[String]` type, while you should just pass a `String`.

Try something like this:

```
func resultOfShuffle(firstCard : Int, secondCard : Int) {

    if firstCard > 33 {
        theResult.image = UIImage(named: cardResults[0])
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, I get the point of this return type! Thank you - I changed it in the same way you did, however, it still shows me that theResult is an unresolved identifier. 

In my `ViewController` I have three statements, every single one of them is executed in the same way:

`@IBOutlet weak var cardOne: UIImageView!`

    `@IBOutlet weak var cardTwo: UIImageView!`

    `@IBOutlet weak var theResult: UIImageView!`

Comment: I can see that even if I start typing in "theResult", the autocompletion doesn't show me any suggestion - just like it didn't exist, even though it is an active outlet in ViewController

Comment: That's strange. The scope of the declaration should be sufficient for `resultOfShuffle(_:, _:)` to see the variable. The function is declared inside the `ViewController`, right?

Comment: @KacperŁuczak Anyway - have you thought it might be a curly braces displacement? Maybe you put some stealthy braces which change the scope of the program: for example, the function which can't get to the `theResult` variable could be **outside** the declaration of the `ViewController`, effectively making the variable not visible to it.

Comment: No, no, the function is declared outside the `ViewController`. Should it be?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Since the function is outside the declaration of the controller, it can't get access to the **local variable** declared inside it. It's a scope problem; it will work when you will put the function inside. I suggest reading something about Scope in Swift - and in programming languages in general - on the internet.

Comment: The first sentence in my answer referred to exactly this, 

`Is every statement executed in the same ViewController? It should recognize theResult as a UIImageView, then.`
If you want to access it from the outside, you should pass it as an argument.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I thought that it doesn't matter where I put my function in the code, but I can see my mistake here. Thank you very much!:)

Comment: @KacperŁuczak I have updated the answer so that it solves the problem correctly. If it has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Done! Sorry, I'm new here :)

Comment: Don't worry, no need to excuse yourself! I was just helping you getting to know this wonderful place. Have fun!